# Custom _app and _document get ignored when moving files to src/pages folder in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The Next.js documentation states, that the directory `src/pages` is an alternative to `/pages`. However, my custom `_app.tsx` and `_document.tsx` files, get ignored when the pages folder is moved into src.

You can recreate this issue yourself, when creating an empty Next.js App, moving the pages folder into src and updating the import paths of the css files. The content of the `index.tsx` file will still be rendered, but modifications to the `styles/globals.css`, which is imported in the `_app.tsx` will have no effect.

It is impossible to have a pages folder inside of src and outside of src at the same time, therefore preventing me to use `src/pages` in any app which needs a modificaton to the `_app.tsx` or `_document.tsx`.

Am I missing an important part of the documentation or does this work as intended?

Comment: Try deleting the `.next` folder and restarting your dev server.

Comment: Deleting works !

Comment: If deleting this folder still not work, maybe you have enabled ```pageExtensions``` feature. Try to rename ```_app.tsx``` to ```_app.page.tsx``` and ```_document.tsx``` to ```_document.page.tsx```

Comment: @juliomalves could you please put your comment in the form of an answer?  This question has sat unanswered for too long.

Comment: the proposed solutions still don't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Changing your project folder structure or adding new `_app`/`_document` files can sometimes lead to caching issues.

Delete the `.next` folder and restart your dev server, to ensure any caching done by Next.js doesn't get in the way.